# Version strings in python using patterns

Tags: python, pandas, string

I created a code to version names in python. The idea is to add v1, v2... if a name already exists in a list. I tried the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

list_names = pd.Series(['name_1', 'name_1_v1'])
name = 'name_1'
new_name = name
i = 1
while list_names.str.contains(new_name).any() == True:
    new_name = f'{name}_v{i}'
    if list_names.str.contains(new_name).any() == False:
        break
    i = i + 1
```

It works fine when I input `'name_1'` (output: `'name_1_v2'`), however, when I enter `'name_1_v1'`, the output is `'name_1_v1_v1'` (correct would be `'name_1_v2'`). I thought of using a regex with pattern _v[0-9]$, but I wasnt able to make it work.

<<< edit >>>

Output should be `new_name = 'name_1_v2'`. The idea is to find an adequate versioned name, not change the ones in the list.

Comment: What would be the expected output: `pd.Series(['name_1_v1', 'name_1_v2'])`?

Comment: Unrelated: instead of `if x == True`, you should just do `if x`. Instead of `if x == False`, do `if not x`

Comment: @DaniMesejo The output is the variable `new_name`, which is just a single name (sorry for not clarifying), in this case `'name_1_v2'`. The list is used only to see if there is need to modify the original name.

Comment: "I thought of using a regex with pattern _v[0-9]$, but I wasnt able to make it work." Well, what regex did you write? How did you apply it? What effect did you expect that to have, and what appeared to happen instead? How does that relate to the inability to solve the overall problem?

Comment: Some enhancements to the approach: 1) Use `itertools.count` to make an indefinite `for` loop with an increasing `i` value (which you can then `break` as currently); 2) build a `set` ahead of time of the strings to check (more efficient data structure for lookup, and avoids repeatedly processing the DataFrame).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Proposed code :**

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

basename = 'name_1'

def new_version(lnam, basename):
    i, lat_v = 0, 0
    # looks for latest version
    while i < len(lnam):
        if re.search('v\d*', lnam[i]) is not None:
            lat_v = max(int(re.findall('v\d*', lnam[i])[0][1:]), lat_v)
        i+=1
    if lat_v == 0:
        return basename + '_v1'
    else:
        return basename + '_v%s'%(lat_v+1)


lnam = pd.Series(['name_1'])
new_name = new_version(lnam, basename)
print("new_name : ", new_name)
# new_name :  name_1_v1

lnam = pd.Series(['name_1', 'name_1_v1'])
new_name = new_version(lnam, basename)
print("new_name : ", new_name)
# new_name :  name_1_v2
```

**Result :**

```
new_name :  name_1_v2
```

Let's try now with an unordered list of names (next version is 101) :

```py
lnam = pd.Series(['name_1', 'name_1_v4', 'name_1_v100', 'name_1_v12', 'name_1_v17'])
new_name = new_version(lnam, basename)
print("new_name : ", new_name)
# new_name :  name_1_v101
```

**Basename automatic identification (like @FernandoQuintino suggests)**

```py
basename = re.sub('_v\d*', '', basename)
# name_1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the idea is to find the value of `new_name`. This variable is the versioned name based on the ones in the list. Thanks again

Comment: @FernandoQuintino : Here is a new version

Comment: The code works correctly versioning when used in conjunction with an adapted `get_basename` function (the function has to be able to deal with user entering versioned names as basenames).

One alternative is to simply add (`basename = re.sub('_v\d*', '', basename)`) in the 'new_version' function. Thanks